# Pentaho Kettle Data Integration - How to do a Loop

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I hope this message finds you all well!

I'm stucked in the following Spoon's situation: I have a variable named Directory. In this variable, I have a path of a directory where the transformation reads a XLS file. After that, I run three jobs to complete my flow.

Now, instead of read just one file, I want to do a loop for it. In other words, after read the first xls file, the process will get the next one in the directory.

For example:

-> yada.xls -> job 1 -> job 2 -> job 3
-> yada2.xls -> job 1 -> job 2 -> job 3

Did you fellas already faced the same situation?

Any help are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Loops are not intuitive or very configurable in Spoon/PDI. Normally, you want to first get all the iterations into a list and copy that to "result rows". The next step then has to be configured to "Execute every input row" (checkbox). You can then pass each row individually to that job/transformation in a loop. Specify each "Stream Column Name" from the result rows under Parameters tab.

Step 1 (generate result rows) --> Step 2 ("Execute every input row")

Step 2 can be a job with multiple steps handling each individual row as parameters.

A related article you may find helpful: https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/using-copy-rows-to-result-in-pentaho-data-integration/